# Clustering a dataset to get the most abnormal data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I have several datasets in R+, each containing two training and test sets. For example the following [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfzw5.png). I want to train a classifier by using training data such that by applying the test data, I get some reasonable number of points as anomaly so that I can analysis the related situations.  The higher the value, the more abnormal it is.

By reasonable number I mean it to be less than P% in each 100 points (each day 100 points are generated, most of them should be considered normal and I want to analysis about P of the most abnormal ones).

I tried K-means with K=2. But as you see in the above link, anomaly cluster is selected by the outliers to be too high. So there would be no anomaly in test data.

Answer (score 0):

The data sets are 1 dimensional, right?

Then you should just be doing kernel density estimation. Don't bother to look at "clustering" algorithms, these are usually designed for multivariate data; they will also be much slower, because multidimensional data cannot be sorted, whereas one dimensional can.